# Why the Canvas window doesn't show up?

Tags: java, netbeans

Why the applet window does not show up, when I run it with Netbeans?

```
package test;

import processing.core.PApplet;


public class Test extends PApplet{

public void setup(){
    size(300, 300);
}
public void draw (){

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

     }

}
```

and its output is like this:

```
run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: There's nothing to run it. You have an empty main method. Implement that, or run it via an applet viewer.

Comment: how can I run it with applet viewer??

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/appletviewer.html.